# about sql and winform

Tags: sql, winforms

Actually i created 2 tables ordm in this i created primary key is orderno ,orderdate,credit term and days and ordc i created foreign key is orderno,item name,price and value in sql server then i created 2 forms for both table in winform then i connected both of them with sql server,but i need to show ordc all column data in gridview with the help of orderno like when i enter order in ordm so it can save data in ordc grid with order detail.but order dont have to show in grid.

i want to show data i grid view from ordm form or order detail wch are in ordc table with help of ordernon

Comment: I am very sorry, but your question is very difficult to understand.  I realise English is not your native language, but maybe it would help to write your question in your own language and use translation software to convert it to English (there are lots available).  It would also improve your question enormously, if you provided some code, illustrating what you are trying to do.